# Batchnorm using Tensorflow is causing Overfitting

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, batch-normalization

I am working on MINST style ASL( Americn Sign Language) recognition problem.
I am epereincing issues with Batchnorm using Tensorflow 2.0

When I use batchnorm I am seeing massive overfitting on validation dataset. See below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape =(784,)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(40,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(30,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(30,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(100,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal",  kernel_regularizer = keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(30,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(25,activation = "softmax"))
```

[Overfitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrZfa.png)

But when I remove batchnorm I get perfect result.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape =(784,)))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(40,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(30,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(30,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(100,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal",  kernel_regularizer = keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(30,activation = "elu", kernel_initializer = "he_normal"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(25,activation = "softmax"))
```

[Not overfitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3cjY.png)

I am not able to understand why batchnorm is causing overfitting here as it supposed to remove the overfitting.
Will apperciate some help understanding this

Zion

Comment: taking a shot in the dark, I guess the number of `BatchNormalization`s are one too many

Comment: Well just tried with 1 batchnorm but still same results

Comment: is the batchnorm `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization`?

Comment: also with 1 batchnorm, were was it uncommented?

Comment: Yes thats from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization. First one was uncommented

Comment: I don't get it. Are you complaining that you get _better accuracy on the validation data_? That is exactly what _reducing overfitting_ means. The batchnorm model isn't overfitting, in fact it seems to be generalizing perfectly -- same performance on training & validation set (now try on the test set...)

Comment: Hi xdurch.. if you see validation loss in attached images, you can see that one with batchnorm is much higher than one without it. if model was generalising then validation loss should be lower.. hence I am getting confused

Comment: Can you try reducing the number of layers and try using a simpler model? Also try dropout.